# I am not able to create build in bubblewrap when i am running bubblewrap build

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, next.js, bubblewrap

i am trying to deploy my next.js PWA app to the Google Play Store i am getting error when i am trying to create build using `bubblewrap build` command after initialisation using `bubblewrap init --manifest=https://beta.oasistravelhousing.com/manifest.json` command.

```
cli ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Users\Victus\.bubblewrap\jdk\jdk-11.0.9.1+1\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx4096m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Victus\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
OpenJDK Client VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Users\Victus\.bubblewrap\jdk\jdk-11.0.9.1+1\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx4096m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Victus\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
OpenJDK Client VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:176)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:137)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:217)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:211)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:133)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:145)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:99)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:294)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:266)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DebugLoggerWarningAction.execute(DebugLoggerWarningAction.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.WelcomeMessageAction.execute(WelcomeMessageAction.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.NativeServicesInitializingAction.execute(NativeServicesInitializingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.DefaultCommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(DefaultCommandLineActionFactory.java:259)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:31)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:63)


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

i am trying deploy my next.js web app to the google play store for that i am using **bubblewrap** after the successful run of the following command
`bubblewrap init --manifest=https://beta.oasistravelhousing.com/manifest.json`
when i am trying to create build using bubblewrap build i am getting error.